# Show that the dual map is well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and $f:V\to W$ a linear map. Define the transpose $f^t:W^*\to V^*$ by $f^t(g)(v)=g(f(v))$.

I want to show that $f^t$ is well-defined and linear. I'm comfortable showing that it's linear but I don't really understand how to show that it is well-defined. How do I do this?

Comment: It is *defined*, no need to do that well. Make sure, however, that for each $g\in W^*$, your $f^t(g)$ is indeed in $V^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing that $f^t$ is linear, you have to show that, for $g\in W^*$, $f^t(g)\colon V\to F$ ($F$ is the base field) is linear. Otherwise $f^t$ wouldn't be a map $W^*\to V^*$.

The map $f^t(g)$ is defined by $v\mapsto g(f(v))$. Since it is the composition of linear maps, it is indeed linear.